# How to execute directive first and then events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive. That directive need to call first. based on that directive returned value remaining functions need to call. But In my scenario first functions are calling after that Directive is calling.

How to call directive first. Is there any priority concept related to this.

**update**

That directive add the formated mask($) [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/4rr7azrj/70/) but it will not effect to ng-model. and That text box contains another function also. So if that function executed first then that ($) symbol will be there in the ng-model. If directive executed first then it will not effect to ng-model. so I want to execute directive first.

```
.directive('format', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        val: '=val'
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

        if (!ctrl) return;
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(a) {

          if (attrs.symbol == '$')
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue, '$')
          else
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
        });

                scope.$watch(function() {
            return elem.val()
        }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
          var a = newVal;
          var plainNumber = a.split('.').filter(function(e) {
            return (e.length > 0);
          }).join('.');
          var i = 0;
          if (isNaN(parseFloat(plainNumber))) {
            i = (attrs.symbol == '$') ? 1 : 3;
          }
          var num = plainNumber.substring(i, plainNumber.length).replace(/,/g, '');
          if (attrs.symbol == '$')
            elem.val($filter('currency')(num, attrs.symbol));
          else
            elem.val($filter('currency')(num));
          var n = parseFloat(num);
          scope.val = Number(n);
          if (!scope.$$phase) {
            scope.$apply();
          }
        });
      }
    };

    // controller 
  }])
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this without knowing what your directive is actually doing, but what you are describing *seems like* something Directives shouldn't be used for.  Directives are meant to affect the element they are attached to;  if the behavior of other parts of the app are dependent on that Directive, then your app probably has an architecture problem.

Comment: @Claies I have edited the question please find

Comment: But that's the entire point I was trying to make.  A Directive is responsible for the DOM manipulation of a specific element;  A Directive should *never* be used to manipulate the `ng-model` value.  if you want to use a `format` directive to remove the extra characters, that should be on the element you want to display, not the element where the value is entered.

Comment: @Claies Okay is there any alternate for this.

Comment: It seems like you want to use a validator here, so that the users can't enter the extra characters.

Comment: yeah I am using validators, But there is a requirement that text box value should visible in $

Comment: Can you tell us what problem you are trying to solve, or what scenario you are working with? It seems that whatever you're trying to do with the code above is unnecessary

Comment: @PixelCakeGames Okay I want to show the $ symbol before my texy box value. And the symbol should not effect to ng-model